Does Last Gasp count Death Defiances used before getting the Boon?
The Last Gasp Boon has the description

Deal more damage for each spent Death Defiance.

Do Death Defiances spent before obtaining this Boon count towards the damage bonus?

While the wording may be confusing, Last Gasp effect could be read as "Deal 10% increased damage for every empty Death Defiance slot". So it's not about the total amount of Death Defiance you used in a run before or after getting the boon, but just a damage increase depending on the amount of Death Defiance slot that are currently empty.
